# Custom dialog becomes the size of the first control in android

Tags: android, dialog

I have the following layout for my custom log in dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_large">
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dialog.login.settings"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_medium" />
    <TextView android:text="@string/dialog.login.text.user_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/dialog.login.user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ems="20"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView android:text="@string/dialog.login.text.password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/dialog.login.password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/dialog.login.show_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dialog.login.check.show_password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:checked="false" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button android:id="@+id/dialog.login.cancel"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_exit_black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:text="@string/dialog.login.button.cancel" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/dialog.login.connect"
            android:text="@string/dialog.login.button.connect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

when I create the dialog and setcontentview the width of the dialog becomes equal to that of the image button on the first row

if I remove that , it becomes the size of the EditText (dialog.login.user_name) whose ems is 20

when I make the dialog's constructor call the base dialog constructor with a theme of R.style.Theme.Material.Dialog it does get the correct (about 3/4 of the screen) but the problem is that it ignores my primary and accent colours (which is normal)

Is there a way to have the dialog have the Theme.Material.Dialog size but still keep my own primary/accent colours?

thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: can u attach some screenshots of what you want and wht u r getting?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching it seems that the solution is to actually replace the `dialogTheme` attribute of my main theme, so the solution was:

```
<style name="app.theme"
    parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/app.dialog</item>
    ......
</style>

<style name="app.dialog"
    parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary.dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```